# Manipulating word docs (doc, docx, etc) in linux with php or ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, linux, ms-word

I have users uploading word documents on my webpage. I need to open these documents, display them in html, and allow the user to download a manipulated version.

My webserver allows me to use PHP and Rails. So a solution in either language would be acceptable.

I have found numerous other posts in my research such as LiveDocx which seems to be more geared only towards creating word documents with known templates. And Java POI which isn't supported by my webserver. 
I have also found information on docx such that I can just unzip it and tweak the xml files -- which would be great except that I would like to accept more extensions than docx alone.

This is my last ditch attempt to find another solution to this problem. Any suggestions? Am I just going to have to switch to a windows server? (even with a windows server, can I do what I want?)

Comment: In what way do you need to manipulate the documents? Does your webserver allow the installation of new apps (i.e. do you have  root access to the server, or a flexible administrator who would do this for you)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not saying what kinds of manipulations you need to apply, nor whether you can install anything new on the server, but if you can, you could install OpenOffice  (or Libreoffice as pointed out by @Rok) and access it from your script through the command line.

OoO can convert all sorts of office formats, including past and current Microsoft office ones, PDF and HTML, and is I think the best tool available for this kind of job.

You could display documents in a converted HTML view, or if that doesn't work (I imagine it would break a *lot* inside complex documents, if it works at all!), a PDF embedded in an iframe, which should be just as well.

This [OpenOffice.org Forum entry](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=7242) provides some starting points.

**Edit:** If you can't install any software, there are third party web services that do conversions, most for a fee. [Here](http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/) is an example.

Comment: I can not install anything on the server as its a shared host. I need to do simple string manipulations on certain sentences in the document. i.e. replacing text with new text.

Comment: @Stephen there are external web services that offer this - ones that charge a fee, and which you send your documents to from your PHP script. And then there is one self-hosted product that claims to do the job: http://www.phpdocx.com/ but it's not free, they offer no trial version, and honestly I don't believe they can do what they claim (generate PDFs out of Word documents without using a web service). So the 3rd party services are the only way to do this I think

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm looking at the third party ones.

Comment: @Stephen no problem. I added one example to the answer, but there are more around.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. Install libreoffice on the server
2. Call libreoffice python scripting with either php or ruby

And don't switch to windows, it won't make the problem easier.